# Non Http Response code: url fail to respond Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, http-response-codes

Today i got issue Non Http Response code when run script on Jmeter. My script run over some steps (Login - view) but got this issue and have log that issue at NoHttpResponseException.
I'm using Jmeter version 3.3. And I think that maybe this issue from server side, not by my script.
Does anyone fix this issue before? Please support me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

This status code is being returned when an [Exception](https://stackify.com/specify-handle-exceptions-java/) occurs during [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler execution. There are hundreds or thousands of possible exceptions and even more potential causes for them.

- If it occurs only under the load - most probably it's a server side error and you need to check the application under test logs and monitoring software results to identify the cause
- It might be something described in the [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed)
- It might be the case your JMeter script is badly designed/implemented and you're sending garbage instead of proper HTTP request

So try to collect as much information as you can:

- Application under test and JMeter logs (it includes any middleware such as reverse proxies, load balancers, databases, etc.)
- Application under test and JMeter machines health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap)
- Network layer information, i.e. HTTP Request and response details.

---

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever is the current latest JMeter version available at [Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as it will be possible.

Comment: Thanks for support Dmitri. It's issue from server side and i also upgrade to 5.0